# Stress, spirantization and other changes in the word "okay"

Tags: english, phonetics, american-english, discourse, interjections

I'm a teenager from the Midwest. In the English language, many words have significant variance in their range of possible pronunciations. Some words may sound different from speaker to speaker in different situations, even among those with basically identical phonologies. Some common interjections, discourse markers, and other function words even have variance in a person's own speech, perhaps even regardless of the formality of the situation. I'm not sure, though, if there are any words with as wide a range as "okay." (Okay, OK, Ok, K, O.K. - even the orthography has a lot of variance!)

First, I've noticed a discrepancy in stress. When I search for phonetic transcriptions of the word, they all place the stress on the second syllable. Despite this, I find it just as intuitive to give more emphasis to the first syllable. In a sentence - especially a question like "Is that okay?" - the final syllable stress sounds correct. However, as an informal, one-word response to another person's comment (which is probably the most common usage of the word anyway), I think there can often be more stress on the initial syllable. Certainly, the intonation (rising vs. falling) plays a major role in this difference. Thus, it seems to me that "okay" has variable stress depending on context and idiolectal variance (I think "hello" may also have variable stress). Perhaps people could be opposed to this "variable stress" idea since it is not standard for the FACE vowel (lexical set) of "okay" to appear in an unstressed syllable.

I've also caught myself producing a different consonant sound for the /k/ than the typical aspirated voiceless velar plosive. Certainly, if the second syllable can be unstressed as I have suggested, a loss of aspiration would be assumed. However, I've noticed a further degree of lenition in my own informal pronunciation of "okay." The voicing never drops off while the consonant is being produced, and the airflow is not fully constricted. I suppose the only way to describe this would be that the /k/ is realized as a voiced velar fricative [ɣ]. This change seems to go hand in hand with the change in stress I described earlier. I don't remember consciously noticing this variant in anyone's speech other than my own.

Are these variations common, or even real? Am I analyzing them correctly?

Comment: I don't know if you're analyzing them correctly, but all those variations occur in speech. The item spelled "OK" has a lot of uses, and a lot of usage by everybody, so variation is normal. Especially since there's normally only two open syllables with two tense vowels with a stop between them, and it's pronounced at speed.

Comment: _Okay_ is also the only English word I know of where /o/ has the variation /m/ or /ŋ/ (m’kay).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You’re right; I hadn’t thought of those variations. It probably has to do with nasals being relatively easy to produce as evidenced by their commonality cross-linguistically.

Comment: Note that you can just hum the entire word and be understood. Nasals are hummed. (You may need an occasional glottal stop) Much the same is true of _oh-oh, oh no!_ and other common interjections. If the word's melody does the job, details about its pronunciation are irrelevant.

Comment: @jlawler You can hum “okay?” Please explain. There’s mm-hm [ʔm˨.m̥m˦], mm-mm [ʔm˦.m˨], uh-huh [ʔə̃˨.hə̃˦], and uh-uh [ʔə̃˦.ʔə̃˨](forgive me if the transcriptions are terrible), but none of those would have ever occurred to me as realizations or “okay.”

Comment: Just as there are many (many many) different melodies for _mm-hmm_, with just as many meanings in context, there are plenty for OK as well.